# Issues with storing data in groups

Tags: python, django

I have made a group *"general"* from admin panel.

Now I want when a new user register to my app it will *by default assign to this group* and `user_id` and `group_id` stored in intermediate table of `auth_user` and `auth_group`.

Actually I have tried this myself and getting errors.

EDIT

```
def signup(request, template="accounts/account_signup.html"):
    """
    Signup form.
    """
    profile_form = get_profile_form()
    form = profile_form(request.POST or None)
    #return render_to_response('test.html',{'q':email},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
        new_user = form.save()
    group_id=Group.objects.get(id=1)
    group_id.groups.add(new_user)
    #group = User_Groups(user=new _user,group=1)
    #group.save()
    last_inserted_id = User.objects.order_by('-id')[0]
    value_email = last_inserted_id.email
    ...............
```

Error

> 'Group' object has no attribute 'groups'

Comment: Please show your attempt and your errors - it'll help people help you

Comment: Which then leads to - how is `Group` defined...

Comment: i have imported group but here i am only showing the function.

Comment: Can you just simply tell me how to store data in intermediate table of  user and group

Comment: I know you've imported `Group` otherwise you'd get a `NameError` - but the error message says it all `Group object has no attribute groups`... hence why I was asking to know what `Group` looked like, and you might even answer your own question if you look...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, to begin with, will help you understand the error you're getting

```
group_id = Group.objects.get(id=1)
```

Here, `group_id` becomes an instance of the model `Group`.
`Group` and its instances have attributes `name`, and `permissions`.

```
group_id.groups.add(new_user)
```

Is nonsense. `groups` is an attribute of `User` and not `Group`.
Replace group_id with new_user :

```
new_user.groups.add(group_id)
```

This will add group_id (which should be named group instead) to the list of groups new_user is member of.